# Liferay 7.1 npm-react-module localization

Tags: reactjs, liferay-7

I'm trying to include localization into my npm-react-module, but I have failed receiving the value for the corresponding key from the Langugage.properties file. It simply returns the key. I did some research but I couldn't find any source that would help me solve my problem.

In the code which I will show you bellow, I have included a Language.properties file into my module. In my portlet, I have included the needed configuration for the language properties. I have also tried to add a separate file for a specific locale, but that didn't help me either.

This is an example of my portlet configuration:

```
"javax.portlet.resource-bundle=content.Language"
```

This is an example content from my Language.properties file:

```
example-key=example-value
```

This is how I'm trying to access the value in my React Component:

```
<h1> {Liferay.Language.get('example-key')} </h1>
```

But it only returns "example-key" instead of "example-value".
In my view.jsp file I am able to retrieve the corresponding values using

```
<liferay-ui:message key='example-key'/>
```

I have tried this method: https://portal.liferay.dev/docs/7-1/tutorials/-/knowledge_base/t/localizing-your-portlet but it didn't work either. Did anyone get this to work properly in their npm-react-module? I really don't want to spend time implementing my own localization service. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Liferay.Language.get('key') gets text replaced by the build mechanism. Therefore there is no actual object/class to do this. I have been trying to get this to work myself and have resolved that I will have to do internationalization on my own.

> localizing is done only in build time meaning if you have a language
> key that generated dynamicly , you can't localizate it or for example
> if you get a key from api fetch and need to localizate it, you can't
> beacuse Liferay localization method for react (
> Liferay.Language.get("yourLanguageKey") ) its undefined in runtime and
> you can't use it.

from: [https://npm.io/package/liferay-react-runtime-localizatio](https://npm.io/package/liferay-react-runtime-localization)n

Comment: I ended up doing the same.